# JTable width height ScrollPane not working

Tags: java, swing, jtable, scrollpane

I have wrote a code for Setting a JTable to a Panel with layout null.
I tried to change its width and height and tried to set a scrollpane horizontally but there is no change

Comment: *"..a Panel with layout null.."*  1) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I too wanted to try what you tried... But couldn't find a piece of code to try upon...

Comment: This usually happens because either you use a `null` layout and/or your screw with the tables `preferredSize`

Comment: panel = new JPanel();

// panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 300));

  // Create columns names

  String columnNames[] = { /****Column name****};

  // Create some data
  String dataValues[][] = { //********Table Data******/ };

  // Create a new table instance

  table = new JTable(dataValues, columnNames);

  table.setSize(800, 900);

  table.setEnabled(false);

  // Add the table to a scrolling pane
  scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
  scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(panel);

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify.  See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

Comment: @Dcoder voting to close too